How to ignore fill rule in PaperJS
I was wondering if someone with more PaperJS experience could help me with this. I'm trying to fill the an entire Path, including its holes and negative spaces.
I understand that I can call resolveCrossings (or unite) to break the path at all self-intersections, but that doesn't seem to account for negative spaces between self-intersections.
For example, the below pathData produces this path:
var path = new Path("M284.16424,537l251.83576,-251.83576l251.83576,251.83576l-503.67153,-251.83576l251.83576,251.83576l251.83576,-251.83576z");`

After calling resolveCrossings the resulted CompoundPath have 6 paths (one of each filled section).

But what I'm looking to achieve is fill everything, including those two negative spaces, resulting in a path that looks something like this:

Here's an example code with the path showed in above example:
var path = new Path("M284.16424,537l251.83576,-251.83576l251.83576,251.83576l-503.67153,-251.83576l251.83576,251.83576l251.83576,-251.83576z");

// Resolve any self-intersections in the path
var result = path.resolveCrossings();
result.fillColor = 'black'

And here's a PaperJS sketch playground with the code:
sketch
I tried calling resolveCrossings to break the path at all self-intersections.

Apparently a limitation.  unite()  works for simple polygons but it seems like paper.js can't handle multiple self-intersections like this. You should try to file an issue on github. resolveCrossings would split all intersections into separate paths.
